# How to set DTS variable value as stored procedure name in Execute Sql Task

Tags: ado.net, ssis

I have execute sql task control ,which is intended to execute a stored procedure , how can i pass the dts variable value as stored procedure name in execute sql task.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change SQLSourceType from "Direct input" to "Variable" and then select the variable you want from the SourceVariable dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can write "exec ?" in the `SQLStatement`field and map the variable in the `Parameter Mapping`sections. This assumes you are not passing extra parameters to the stored procedure though.
Also, this method works for OLEDB connectors. I believe this is different in ADO.NET connectors

To pass parameters to an ADO.NET connector, you use `@VariableName` Instead of the "?". 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502.aspx

In the link above scroll down to the section "Passing parameters to a stored procedure". It describes the process in detail

Comment: Their is some way out to do in ado.net but i am not finding that any where?